How to do pdf summarization using claude 3 API on AWS bedrock?
I am trying to use Claude 3 API on AWS Bedrock to do summarizations of posts which may have pdf or images attached along with the text.
def invoke_claude_3_with_text(self, prompt):
    client = self.bedrock_client
    model_id = "anthropic.claude-3-sonnet-20240229-v1:0"

    try:
        response = client.invoke_model(
            modelId=model_id,
            body=json.dumps(
                {
                    "anthropic_version": "bedrock-2023-05-31",
                    "max_tokens": 2048,
                    "messages": [
                        {
                            "role": "user",
                            "content": [{"type": "text", "text": prompt}],
                        }
                    ],
                }
            ),
        )

        # Process and print the response
        result = json.loads(response.get("body").read())
        input_tokens = result["usage"]["input_tokens"]
        output_tokens = result["usage"]["output_tokens"]
        output_list = result.get("content", [])

I am using above code for text summarization and is working as expected. Even the way forward with images is clear where I will be base64 encoding them and sending to Claude APIs.
I am not so clear on how can I get summary of a pdf document. Do I have to extract text out of pdf first and send that to Claude or is there some other direct way like how it works with images ? What if my pdf has images inside of it ?

Yes, you'll need to extract text from the PDF first before passing it to Claude 3 API for summarization. If the PDF contains images, you may need to perform additional processing such as OCR to include that information in the summary.
So following will be the flow:

Extract Text from PDF
Invoke Claude 3 API
Handle Images (If any)
Summarize

You can use the PyPDF2 library to extract text from PDF.
pip install PyPDF2

You can refer sample code
def extract_text_from_pdf(self, pdf_path):
    text = ""
    try:
        with open(pdf_path, "rb") as file:
            pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(file)
            num_pages = pdf_reader.numPages
            for page_num in range(num_pages):
                page = pdf_reader.getPage(page_num)
                text += page.extractText()
        return text
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error extracting text from PDF:", e)
        return None

